# Constrained Minimization with variables related in a numeric map in python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have the following optimization problem-with 4 variables (x1,x2,y1,y2)
Minimize (x1^2+x2^2) under the constraints-
T=x1.y1-x2.y2=Constant
y1=f(x1,x2)                    { y1 is given in a 2d map with x1 and x2 as inputs}
y2=g(x1,x2)                   { y2 is given in 2d map with x1 and x2 as inputs }

I am unable to use the Scipy optimization routine since y1 and y2 are not expressed as analytic function but as a numeric 2d map. How do I go about solving it?

Regards,
Surajit

Comment: Scipy does not require analytic functions. The only problem I see that you cannot provide gradients. Scipy will typically use finite differences, but it may be better to use a derivative free solver like Cobyla (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-cobyla.html).

Comment: Hi Erwin, can you give an example that uses Cobyla for similar problems?